# Salesforce: Mapping Fields

Tags: php, salesforce

I need suggestion regarding how can I map below fields which we are using as affiliates.

```
1) Affiliates/Account
2) Account Users
3) Account Manager
4) Offer
5) Advertiser
```

Below is current relationship between them --

```
i) Affiliates : Users - 1:M
ii) Affiliates : Account Manager - 1:1
iii) Affiliate : Offer - 1:M
iv) Advertiser : Affiliates - 1:M
v) Offer : Advertiser - 1:1
```

For now, we are mapping with SF as,

```
1) Affiliates >> ACCOUNTS
2) Account Users >> CONTACTS
```

Please advice on mapping.

Regards.

Comment: When you say mapping, are you referring to the object relationships?

Comment: @geekymartian -- Yes, I am referring to object relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i) Affiliates (one to many) Users:
```

Create a lookup relationship on the User object pointing to Affiliates object

```
ii)  Affiliates (one to one) Account Manager:
```

Create a lookup relationship on Affiliates pointing to Account Manager, add a trigger at account Manager to prevent having more than 1 affiliate.

```
iii) Affiliate (one to many) Offer:
```

Create a lookup relationship on the Offer object pointing to Affiliate

```
iv) Advertiser (one to many) Affiliates:
```

Create a lookup relationship on the Advertiser object pointing to Affiliates

```
v) Offer (one to one) Advertiser
```

Create a lookup relationship on Offer pointing to Advertiser, add a trigger at Advertiser to prevent having more than 1 affiliate.